# He who has the largest real number in $[0,1]$ wins

Tags: probability, game-theory

Let's play a game:

> Let $X,Y \sim U (0,1)$ be random variables uniformly distributed over
>   $[0,1]$.
>
> The game is as follows:
>
> 1. I obtain a realization of $X$. You obtain a realization of $Y$.
> 2. If dissatisfied with the realization we obtained, each of us can keep realizing $X$ or $Y$, respectively, until we get a real number we like. I don't know how many realizations you got, and you don't know how many
>      realizations I got. If we get a new realization, the past realizations
>      are forgotten. Only the latest one matters.
> 3. Once we decide to play, we compare the latest realizations we got. Whoever has the largest real number wins $\$1$.

What is the **optimal strategy**? More precisely, what is the threshold $\gamma \in [0,1]$ such that one stops obtaining new realizations once one obtains one that exceeds it?

---

**Hints:**

- Think of this as a simultaneous game that is played over **infinitely**
  many rounds, a bit like rock-paper-scissors.
- At each round of the game, the loser does not pay the winner $\$1$. Rather, some **third party** pays the winner $\$1$
- One can think of player $i$'s strategy as a function $\gamma_i : \mathbb{N} \to [0,1]$, where $\gamma_i (k)$ is the threshold used by player $i$ at round $k$.
- Each player can adjust his threshold based on the other player's past thresholds, i.e., $\gamma_i (k)$ can be a function of $\gamma_j (0), \gamma_j (1), \dots, \gamma_j (k-1)$, where $j \neq i$.

Comment: I feel you should repeat step two indefinitely until you get $1$.  You should add that they can know how many realizations you attempted, it would make the game cooler and possibly more intense.

Comment: You will never get $1$, of course. I'm fairly sure that without further structure to the problem, it's optimal to enter an infinite loop at 2. If you ever stop, at $x$ say, the other person could have looped until they got $(1+x)/2$ or bigger.

Comment: Well, ​ $\gamma = 1$ , ​ for the reason Patrick Stevens gave. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer If $\gamma = 1$, the Sun will explode before we get to compare our realizations.

Comment: That's correct. ​ ​

Comment: Here is a more sensible game.  Say there is a limit, like $10$ to the number of realizations.  I can keep going (up to $10$ times), and stop whenever I want, but my value is the last one.  This type of problem is known (under another name) in the literature.  But think about it before looking it up.

Comment: What happens if I use the strategy "always realize another number"? Is that not valid? Do I have to choose a strategy that almost always chooses a number? Or a strategy which always chooses a number? The question's not really complete without such information.

Comment: Have the pay-off decrease for each player according to the number of iterations otherwise there is no incentive to stop.

Comment: Whoever picks the highest cut off point is most likely to win.  Specifically, if the players each elect to stop as soon as you realise a number higher than $\gamma_X, \gamma_Y$ respectively, then they will wind up with final values distributed: $X_{\mathsf{fin}} \sim \mathcal U[\gamma_X; 1), Y_{\mathsf{fin}}\sim\mathcal U[\gamma_Y; 1)$, so then if, say, $\gamma_X>\gamma_Y$ and specifically $\gamma_X=0.9, \gamma_Y=0.8$ then $$\mathsf P(X_{\mathsf{fin}}>Y_{\mathsf{fin}}) = \tfrac{\gamma_X-\gamma_Y}{1-\gamma_Y}+\tfrac {1-\gamma_X}{2(1-\gamma_Y)} \\ \qquad ~=~ \tfrac 3 4$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Exactly!!! However, if I know your threshold, I have an incentive to change mine. Is there a threshold such that one has no incentive to change it provided that ones knows the other player's threshold?

Comment: Not if there is no limit on number of available rerolls; one simply picks an arbitrary high threasehold; the closer it is to one the closer to certainty the probability of exceeding the other's final result.

Comment: @GrahamKemp The goal is to win the dollar. If both players successively raise their thresholds until both are using $\gamma = 1$, then they never get to compare their numbers, which means that none of them ever win the dollar. Note that this is a **positive sum** game, unlike the traditional rock-paper-scissors. The dollar comes from someone else. The player who loses does not pay the winner anything.

Comment: Yes, the higher the cuttoff the longer it takes until a trial realises a value above it.  But you placed no limitations on the length of the game so there is no optimal choice; the player's decision will only depend on their patience.

Comment: @GrahamKemp You're misunderstanding the game. You're thinking in terms of competition between the two players, rather than considering the possibility of the two players colluding to extract money from whoever is organizing the game.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a variant of your game:

> Each player secretly writes down a number less than $1.0$. The player who
>   wrote down the higher number wins.

I hope it's clear that this is a very silly game! But it is isomorphic to the one that you describe.

Comment: The game you proposed is one where each player chooses a number. The one that I proposed is one where each player chooses a **threshold** and when to **stop**. Big difference.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo A higher threshold corresponds to a better strategy - i.e. their expected payout is greater when the threshold is higher, regardless of what strategy the opponent adopts. So the ordering on the strategies you consider is precisely the ordering on $[0,1)$ - which is what this answer says. The payouts in this game are different than yours, but you asked a question about the optimal strategy, and this game is close enough to preserve that ordering.

Comment: @MiloBrandt If your threshold is higher than mine, then I can raise mine, as I can estimate your threshold based on your previous plays. At some point, we will both be using $\gamma =1$, at which point none of us will ever be comparing any numbers, which means none of us can win any dollars. I mentioned "rock-paper-scissors" in the hint for a reason.

Comment: @MiloBrandt What if both players choose $\gamma = 0$? That would be pure **collusion**, extracting $\$1$ from the game's organizer every round the game is played. By contrast, $\gamma = 1$ is pure **competition**, but fruitless, as neither player can extract any dollars from the game's organizer. What you claim to be optimal is anything but.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo If you want to look at it like that, this is nothing more nor less than a one-shot prisoners' dilemma, surely.